# How should I use proxy in a web app made with node.js and vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

I have a web app made in node.js and vanilla javascript. I wanna replace "http://localhost:4000/api/word" with "api/word" in the fetch api so that it works when the app's deployed on Heroku. I solved the issue by adding "proxy" : "http://localhost:4000" in package.json file when I used React for other apps but I don't know how to deal with the issue when I'm not using React.

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const fs = require("fs");

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.get("http://localhost:4000/api/word", function (req, res) {
  fs.readFile("./wordlist.txt", (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    let wordList = data.toString().split("\n");
    res.send(wordList);
  });
});
```

main.js

```
function getWord() {
  fetch("/api/word")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
     ...do something...
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

I tried the React way but it sends the get request to localhost:5500 which is the client side port.

Comment: Where are you sending the request from.  Is it supposed to be from the file that is being served by your server?

Comment: It's sending the request from the client side which runs on port 5500. The server runs on port 4000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your client and server are listening on different ports, I'm assuming your server isn't serving the client and that it has its own server. If the client doesn't need its own separate server, you can serve it from your express app by putting it in a directory and using `express.static`. Assuming you put the frontend code in a directory called `public` next to your server code, that would look like this:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')));
```

If you do need to have a separate server for the client, there are modules just for this problem. `http-proxy` is a very popular one. I provided examples of how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65694088/5774952) that could be easily adapted for any Node server, but there are many more in [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy).

Also just a sidenote, `app.get("http://localhost:4000/api/word", function (req, res)` should be `app.get('/api/word' ...`: your routes shouldn't define the scheme, host, and port.